# Input multiple objects of a class in a single HTML or Flask form

Tags: html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

For the sake of simplicity, say I want to build a shopping list using Flask using a table in a format that looks like this:

| Name | Cost | Amount | Sell-By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 1 | 5 | 2022-07-18 |
| Bananas | 0.7 | 7 | 2022-07-20 |

I want the shopping list page to initially look like this, with a user able to add any number of items before submission

| Name | Cost | Amount | Sell-By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (User input) | (User input) | (User input) | (User input) |

When submitted each line should be able to be initiated as a SQLAlchemy object and saved into a database.

I've tried using FieldList and FormField from WTForms but can't quite get the hang of it (and don't really feel it's appropriate in this situation anyway). I don't usually struggle with forms, but having multiple instances of the same form AND trying to put that in a dynamically generated table is really tripping me up, so any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The content/size of a shopping list should be adjustable during writing.
Therefore i suggest you take a look at JavaScript and add a simple Button that generates a new row´each time you click it. Each row then contains the needed String or Number fields.

If you send the form you can simply move the entries to your Database